# How to add redirection rule using htacess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to write htaccess redirection rule for redirect url from 'abc.com/xyz' to 'abc.com/t1=xyz'. But rule not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
#RewriteRule ^xyz$ /?t1=xyz [L]
```

Please help me on this.

```
1.) abc.com/xyz output abc.com?t1=xyz
2.) abc.com/xzzz output abc.com?t1=xzzz
```

value after domain is not fixed this can be changed. Anything after domain should be value of t1 after redirection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, written as per your shown samples. Please make sure you clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ ?t1=$1 [L]
```